# Setting a Sublime Text shortcut for 'Edit - Wrap - Wrap at XX characters'

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to set a shortcut for the `Edit - Wrap - Wrap at XX characters` command in Sublime Text 3.

I'm aware of the AutoWrap package, but that works as you write splitting long lines into new ones.

The article [Adding Word Wrap Toggle Shortcut Key in Sublime Text 3](https://medium.com/@f1lt3r/adding-word-wrap-toggle-shortcut-key-in-sublimetext3-a2d0ccf616cb) explains how to add a shortcut but not to break long lines, it just wraps them.

I need to wrap at 80 chars, but it'd be great if I could set the `XX` number of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command that the menu items you reference above use to perform the wrap is the `wrap_lines` command. It takes an argument `width` that specifies at what column the wrap should occur, so you can provide any width you want in your binding, or have multiple bindings to have multiple pre-set wrap amounts.

For example:

```
{
    "keys": ["super+w"],
    "command": "wrap_lines",
    "args": {
        "width": 80
    },        
},  
{
    "keys": ["shift+super+w"],
    "command": "wrap_lines",
    "args": {
        "width": 40
    },        
},
```

The `width` argument to the command is optional; if you don't provide it, Sublime chooses a default:

1. The column set in the `View > Word Wrap Column` menu
2. If the wrap column is set to `Automatic`, the ruler from the `View > Ruler` menu
3. If the ruler is set to `None`, then the wrap happens at column 78.

Note also that the value of the wrap column can be adjusted infinitely by altering the `wrap_width` setting, and the list of rulers can be adjusted to whatever you want by using the `rulers` setting. The related menu items are just modifying the value of the setting in the current view.

As a note on `rulers`, there can be more than one of them listed; if that is the case, the first one in the list would be used as the wrap point in #2 above.